# Removing list items based on presence of a sub-list

Tags: r

I have a list and I would like to remove any list object with a sublist. In the example below, I would like to remove `ob2` and `ob5` and keep all other objects.

```
dat <- list(ob1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
            ob2 = list(a = c("d")),
            ob3 = c("e", "f", "g"),
            ob4 = c("h", "i", "j"),
            ob5 = list(1:3))
```

Can anyone offer a solution of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a condition with `sapply` (from `base R`)

```
dat[!sapply(dat, is.list)]
```

Or with `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(Negate(is.list), dat)
```

Or with `discard`

```
library(purrr)
discard(dat, is.list)
```